# Cant connect to Firebase from my Raspberry pi

Tags: python, firebase, raspberry-pi, python-requests

I'm having some issues with my raspberry setup.

The test:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
import json

firebase_url = 'https://myDb.firebaseio.com'
name = 'db_name'
test = {}
print(firebase_url + '/' + name + '/setup.json')
test = requests.get(firebase_url + '/' + name + '/setup.json')
test = test.json()

print(test)
```

Runs on my laptop with no problems. On the Raspberry Pi I get this:

```
https://myDb.firebaseio.com/db_name/setup.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 516, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 304, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 724, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 203, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 133, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 64, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 530, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 362, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
    _pool=self, _stacktrace=stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 245, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 624, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 516, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 304, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 724, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 203, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 133, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 64, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 530, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_fire.py", line 11, in <module>
    test = requests.get(firebase_url + '/' + name + '/setup.json')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 457, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 569, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known'))
```

I get that it means that it can't connect. Why it can't connect is another question though. I'm running this test while logged in over SSH with [weaved](https://www.weaved.com). So internet is up and running without any problems. I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I just don't know where to look.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a DNS problem and everything was fixed by adding nameserver 8.8.8.8 to /etc/resolv.conf...

Case closed.